# Golf hole with multiple pars

Tags: golf

What do the numbers 4/3 and 4/5 mean on a golf hole score card?

USGA no help.

Which number do I use when par on a golf hole is 4/3 or 4/5?

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! I am not going to offer a full answer as I am not a golfer. However, could this possibly be due to start position for men vs. women?

Comment: Do you have an image of such a card that can be part of your question?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of your question, the par used will depend on the tee used.  The par value of a hole is determined by it's length relative to the player.  This means that men and women have different par values for the same distances in some cases.

For men, the distances determining par value were [last adjusted in 1956](https://www.liveabout.com/par-3-to-5-yardage-guidelines-1564466) to match the following:

> Par 3: Up to 250 yards
>
> Par 4: 251 to 470 yards
>
> Par 5: 471 yards or more

For women, the values vary only slightly.

> Par 3:    Up to 210 yards
>
> Par 4:    211 to 400 yards
>
> Par 5:    401 yards or more

To see how this works on a scorecard, take the following sample into consideration.

[image: scorecard]

You can see for hole 3, the yardage from the blue tees is 446 yards, from the white is 441 yards, and from the gold is 386 yards.  For men, this hole is always going to be a par 4 regardless of which tee you use.  However for women, this hole would be a par 4 if played from the gold tees and a par 5 if played from the blue or white tees.

To this end, you'll also often see scorecards with a separate row for men's and women's par values such as this one.  As you can see below, holes 7 and 9 are considered  par 5s for women and par 4s for men, leading to a difference of 2 strokes for a par round.

[image]